# Can't load array data in a class array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, class, var

Hello everyone i would like to get data from 3 arrays for creating map annotations. But i could not load data from those 3 arrays to a class. Here is my code:

My class file:

```
import MapKit
class Jobdata: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let title: String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    init(title: String,  coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        super.init()
    }
}
```

These are my arrays:

```
var jobNameST = [String]()
var jobLongitudeST = [Double]()
var jobLatitudeST = [Double]()
```

And this is my locations array:

```
let jobLocations = [Jobdata(title: "test", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.4692991035765, longitude:  -97.7660876))]
```

I would like to add those 3 arrays to my locations array.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create location model
I Hope all arrays have same number of records
Please check before if not

```
struct Location 
{
    var title: String?
    var latitude: Double?
    var longitude: Double?

    init(title: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.title = title
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}
```

create location model array from given title, latitude and longitude arrays

```
    func getLocations() -> [Location] {

            var locations = [Location]()
            for (index, value) in jobNameST.enumerated() {
                let location = Location(title: value, latitude: jobLatitudeST[index], longitude: jobLongitudeST[index])
                locations.append(location)
            }
            return locations
   }
```